# Selecting a related set of objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    value = models.CharField()
```

`ModelB` always belongs to a `ModelA`. I have a certain query that filters my `ModelB`s:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(value='foo')
```

From that `QuerySet` I need to retrieve the matching `ModelA` set. So I tried this:

```
>>> ModelB.objects.filter(value='foo').values('a')
[{'a': 2}, {'a': 4}, {'a': 6}]
```

But as you can see that only got me the object `id`s. How can I fetch the objects themselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want ModelAs, you have to ask for ModelAs.

```
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__value='foo')
```

Comment: I had no idea this was possible. Can you please explain the resulting SQL from this query?

Comment: It's just a JOIN. Try it yourself in the shell, then do `from django.db import connection; connection.queries` to show the SQL.

Comment: You can also see what the resulting query is by appending ".query" to your QuerySet call. In your example: `print str(ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__value='foo').query)` would give you the resulting query.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have this little number:

```
model_a_list = ModelB.objects.filter(value='foo').values('a')
ModelA.objects.filter(id__in=model_a_list)
```

Any better ways to do this would be much appreciated.